# How can I make this generic TypeScript function work as expected?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm attempting to define a function that works well with the type system in TypeScript, such that I can take a key of an object and, if that key's value needs some modification (converting a custom `string` type to a `boolean` here in my example), I can do that without casting the types.

[Here's a TypeScript playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=95&ssc=38&pln=95&pc=44#code/C4TwDgpgBAKjBOBXCB5eAxAhgGwM7QF4oByYJCYqAHxIDMd9iAoAYwHsA7XYKYNgITZtsUIgApgtAFywEyNFjwQAlDIBGQ7BEwdRAPl61RBIqXLMmAektQA7tAAWmAG7RMUWhFseAlhGwAJrh20LY6PHxQYPBsLBC4uAB0UADKbAC2bvDQHIjpahDwuAA0ULgZWdAsDhAsANYaAB4AtNg+ddDOOMi4VjbATjz2UNnR8RAcQz4DUAAGcOQKDBCziUygkLDobPDpACKYwO5EAN5MUFAg8WgAcmwAij3APpwyC-IYy+ce2RC0O+lHvFnq8oLl8oUmABfJh9MqYTJQDogYKYYIwba7A5HUpqRA8dgcVzwHjvVCfJS8NhQdwaYRQHxcYDaAKlCCJADmyX+8BpUAAUikUDcoABBAAKAEl1uBoDAUog1Olppj0jA2KKwD5RFAzhcrrhbg8ni8OOpNNoON9aL8eYCTaDwQV4NDYdZeA4fMEvR7oLREBwWCDdANDnY2IhAlEYnEElBOH6Ab5-AEaTx3M9Mmt3cMnK4qVBCcSIjVZIsKfgC7TNB4dh6ff7A8G1oTuGVFcrgKr0H4o0QADw9lM3BHQCCNZkcIJIiAgNhGDEA7GYPRib4XWi9gIjzIyIeBHcQYrrqBdbDIN4KpUqgHqzU+ADa++3o4AukxlPpdVBLAAqMoVIWbABI4hTQL+lgwnCAwNgGQammUDgRlGRwdPGHCJrsyZRjoqbTMQwRnsgcK4WUEx4Tw85GJEAzQBKkq4iAvhFOmAQAFaINwjIcmWHyKJWRHxAWdJaDoSSsJwbZOFOWhXp2Or9iez6HlA46TtOyLzlsS6HJg3yriem7DqOe5boex4XBcglvKqy5PmZb4fl+eo-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-z14p0LW4i1L4uIjjV2GuDd1Q9nlm55oBfnkXvEBcs5eWUvUEVTYsXuQMEYcg4PDpJgIAnfFOhQJxbhQPvuQ4LjVQ1PU2WNvBnDs1zPBVTVUB1RA239KW9BBvlXyVsgo+ncAGBCWkwBsASD4NQWgyhkG4t6YI5RMhIW8PvOo2UXphncmESYP8CwtxqOlAIf1NwsEjMAAA-N8VsXNcAAE1rp3B1ADM0UBgGqA8LoH0w8Vos0oAQAwA9CAmEZiw3291YRrzBKVEYfwwKBmyjrYaGF4BjRvj8DIXVH7BlKMA56OwNZQBIdrJCiAd7tyAkyd6zCR53AAGoACY2G0A4QAUQnPATAQZ+yaQXLZXSMVEEcA5Hobh7j3oSIcVIqGX5RHGFBpIse60ZGuXjHUGK1ItDAAIrweATFMAckwIycqyUoBiC9PYo0LiAaZxUDDQO79NZoXml1dgPUfB9RNv4PwrhgjAOiRwJ27tqYv0AQbGOPARnwGdoHHWnd8AAEdkCTC0e5ECm4MKph5HtQuswZDzCCUceyxlMiPSTl3bsvd07YSBkeO5U9Zby0Vuk2RooeCiTbA1Mi1VgiRFsMYuRtgJnTAQd0kQ-N6htyuZ2G5KY+6i1ERPC4zz86CRpMXL6i83kXBhFBd0JVmSTK3pYvKOs0ajTrFpWY0kAiyWTjbHGXp+ZCVsLlOwgw4p1wKSAFR1I3bHh2qWTpeteQBhAixXCwQcE8DwZ5cFzdqQ2h0TrFgOA2hhKiIUXAkB4L5jDN84Aid6WMq7mIfho9BGlGIPQJQ0MmBmogHJaYlqfapNZrasgyBHXOtdcAd1KSbUkFwBYqMhQYjwGhhk8c+qsYeFKeebIsJ-XJ0tTaCAfwASeuILa4lfInSFBje6ONtQE30G6YgFNaaLV2ttDmkNABmZxn5U24XNZ2S1kadi5ttWG1qqk5k7BLTYMtQZqaJqrTWjtLr03EB7fAPtUAACMrbY2NHjZOytybv5uhsDABwMRyU0mwCILSDVSi13JoBSIaJ+aIl2mANKlFqKlmiGwOB1Vom7VQRAGC2r3LPrjGjL2tbOwB3dHs2mDSwrsGRhCs9vT4xvugOAzgWjvbBshutagdAG27FzWFL+rdE7ujEMTQ62BDg5HkXUeaKi-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-1EkMytczEvTTA6Hp9FxJD0dcCZeMTFUc0ZP1aHroyYmIEuqzab+H7dSOELE0DOY6AgdCQsGyCSjjYAD8TCOPdYIz6fE8-1h94IPMbWakE6RZXfHGHWEqDgZoM-eAZvECJuQpGkDQVwOFQWdINOKWe5cyJ5AQaeV5Cub4AlRzNfEQIFeOYIVVeuBrfEY-aPJ1evLuRvOA8PINWJZdOLB1BWbPc-XPefOJdaW1IFdZcguoR1OET5T+bQH5UsWA+AydYkYmDDDfOvPbVueMWiXkDzA-HKGYCMXkSmNsQ4ZkHqYAYVdeYOcFEqT+TgYaXkXxOIMAYAAFUscXFbRnWUWVGoMOP0LcR2TIfJD7YZeRPVWoP6TRCYbeBwBgvbANZg+AsQUreaATBpW1e1RgbgxgzseI1gpI-jCrAAFlbX3S1xcLAj5Baw522WgF2wZX2wgwZF0HcEqN2l8U9HNiEiCNwEwE8FAFKCPzTzv0RybAQlIgjDMN0IsQJEjm4loWsCAA) that has the same walk-through but makes it easier to see the compiler errors.

Some helper types to get my example started:

```
type TTrueOrFalse = 'true' | 'false'
const toBool = (tf: TTrueOrFalse): boolean => tf === 'true'
```

We have a few fields we want to process. Some are numbers, some are checkbox-like values that we represent with `TTrueOrFalse`.

```
type TFormData = {
  yesOrNoQuestion: TTrueOrFalse
  freeformQuestion: number
}

// same keys as TFormData, but convert TTrueOrFalse to a bool instead, e.g. for a JSON API
type TSubmitFormToApi = {
  yesOrNoQuestion: boolean
  freeformQuestion: number
}
```

This is the function that would process one form field at a time. we have to convert the `TTrueOrFalse` to a `boolean` for this function.

```
const submitFormField = <FieldName extends keyof TFormData>(
    fieldName: FieldName,
    value: TSubmitFormToApi[FieldName]
) => { /* some code here */}
```

Here's the problem. This function should take one form field and it's value and send it off to the API, by first adjusting `TTrueOrFalse` values to `booleans`.

```
const handleSubmit = <
    FieldName extends keyof TFormData
  >(
    fieldName: FieldName,
    value: TFormData[FieldName]
) => {
  // I want to convert `TTrueOrFalse` to a `bool` for my API, so I check if we are dealing with that field or not.
  // seems like this check should convince the compiler that the generic type `FieldName` is now `'yesOrNoQuestion'` and
  // that `value` must be `TFormData['yesOrNoQuestion']`, which is `TTrueOrFalse`.
  if (fieldName === 'yesOrNoQuestion') {

    // `value` should be interpreted as type `TTrueOrFalse` since we've confirmed `fieldName === 'yesOrNoQuestion'`, but it isn't
    submitFormField(
      fieldName,
      toBool(value) // type error
    )

    // Looks like the compiler doesn't believe `FieldName` has been narrowed down to `'yesOrNoQuestion'`
    // since even this cast doesn't work:
    submitFormField(
      fieldName,
      toBool(value as TTrueOrFalse) // type error
    )

    // so I'm forced to do this, which "works":
    submitFormField(
      fieldName as 'yesOrNoQuestion',
      toBool(value as TTrueOrFalse)
    )
  }

  // so I thought maybe I can use a manual type checking function, but it seems like
  // the fact that `FieldName` is a union of possible strings is somehow making what I want
  // to do here difficult?
  const isYesOrNo = (fn: FieldName): fn is 'yesOrNoQuestion' => fieldName === 'yesOrNoQuestion'

  // not referencing the generic type from the function, FieldName, works here though:
  const isYesOrNoV2 = (fn: Extract<keyof TFormData, string>): fn is 'yesOrNoQuestion' => fieldName === 'yesOrNoQuestion'

  // ok, so let's try again.
  if (isYesOrNoV2(fieldName)) {
    // seems like now the compiler believes FieldName is narrowed, but that doesn't narrow
    // the subsequent type I defined for `value`: `TFormData[FieldName]`
    submitFormField(
      fieldName,
      toBool(value) // type error
    )

    // At least this seems to work now, but it still sucks:
    submitFormField(
      fieldName,
      toBool(value as TTrueOrFalse)
    )
  }
}
```

Note that, though the interior of `handleSubmit` has issues with what I'm trying to do, the compiler understands what I want it to do from the calling perspective at least:

```
handleSubmit('yesOrNoQuestion', 'false')
handleSubmit('yesOrNoQuestion', 'true')
handleSubmit('yesOrNoQuestion', 'should error') // fails as expected

handleSubmit('freeformQuestion', 'not a number') // fails as expected
handleSubmit('freeformQuestion', 32) 

handleSubmit('errorQuestion', 'should error') // fails as expected
handleSubmit('errorQuestion', 12) // fails as expected
```

Through all of this, I've come to assume that part of the problem is that something I pass into `handleSubmit` for `fieldName` could still be of the union type `'yesOrNoQuestion' | 'freeformQuestion'` like this:

```
// (simulate not knowing the fieldName at compile time)
const unknownFieldName: Extract<keyof TFormData, string> = new Date().getDay() % 2 === 0 ? 'yesOrNoQuestion' : 'freeformQuestion'

// now these compile, problematically, because the expected value is of type `'true' | 'false' | number`
// but I don't want this to be possible.
handleSubmit(unknownFieldName, 2)
```

Ideally, the only way I could call `handleSubmit` dynamically would be by mapping over an object of type `TFormData` and calling `handleSubmit` with each key/value pair that would be known to be the correct type by the compiler.

What I really want to define for `handleSubmit` is a function that takes exactly one key of `TFormData` and a value of the key's corresponding value type. I don't want to define something that is allowed to take a union type for the `fieldName` but I don't know if that's possible?

I thought maybe function overloading could help, though it'd be a pain to define this for a longer form type:

```
function handleSubmitOverload(fieldName: 'yesOrNoQuestion', value: TTrueOrFalse): void
function handleSubmitOverload(fieldName: 'freeformQuestion', value: number): void
function handleSubmitOverload<FieldName extends keyof TFormData>(fieldName: FieldName, value: TFormData[FieldName]): void {
  if (fieldName === 'yesOrNoQuestion') {

    // This still doesn't work, same problem inside the overloaded function since the 
    // concrete implementation's parameter types have to be the same as the non-overloaded try above
    submitFormField(
      fieldName,
      toBool(value) // type error
    )
  }
}

// still works from the outside:
handleSubmitOverload('yesOrNoQuestion', 'false')
handleSubmitOverload('yesOrNoQuestion', 'wont work') // fails as expected

// At least the overloaded version does handle this other problem with our first attempt,
// since it no longer accepts the union of value types when the field name's type is not specific enough
handleSubmitOverload(unknownFieldName, 'false') // error, no matching overload
handleSubmitOverload(unknownFieldName, 42) // error, no matching overload
```

Is there a way to define `handleSubmit` in a way that achieves type safety, inside the function and out, without casting?

Edit: I think it's worth noting that I know something like this will work:

```
const handleSubmitForWholeForm = (
  formField: keyof TFormData,
  form: TFormData
) => {
  if (formField === 'yesOrNoQuestion') {
    submitFormField(formField, toBool(form[formField]))
  }
}
```

but this is not how the real code I'm basing this question off of is structured.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't yet know how to narrow *type parameters* via control flow analysis (see [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085))
.  Meaning that if you make your `handleSubmit()` function generic in the field name type `N`, checking the value of `fieldName` will not narrow `N` itself, and thus the type of `TFormData[N]` will also not be narrowed.

One possible way to proceed is to make the function concrete and not generic.  But how can we keep the `fieldName` and the `value` parameters correlated?  We can use [rest parameter tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions).  Specifically, if we make a type `AllParams` defined like this:

```
type AllParams = { [N in keyof TFormData]: [N, TFormData[N]] }[keyof TFormData]
// type AllParams = ["yesOrNoQuestion", TTrueOrFalse] | ["freeformQuestion", number]
```

then we can make the signature of `handleSubmit` something like `(...nv: AllParams) => void`.  `AllParams` is a union of all the acceptable pairs of `fieldName` and `value` (and the definition above should scale with longer forms).

Here's the `handleSubmit()` implementation:

```
const handleSubmit = (...nv: AllParams) => {
  if (nv[0] === "yesOrNoQuestion") {
    submitFormField(nv[0], toBool(nv[1]));
  } else {
    submitFormField(nv[0], nv[1]);
  }
}
```

You can't destructure `nv` into separate `fieldName` and `value` variables, or the correlation between them will be lost.  Instead you have to use `nv[0]` and `nv[1]` and rely on control flow analysis to narrow `nv` based on testing `nv[0]`, as shown above.

This function should work like your overloaded one in that it only accept pairs of parameters of the right type and will not accept unions-of-field-names:

```
handleSubmit('yesOrNoQuestion', 'false') // okay
handleSubmit('yesOrNoQuestion', 'wont work') // error
handleSubmit('freeformQuestion', 3); // okay
handleSubmit(Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'yesOrNoQuestion' : 'freeformQuestion', 1); // error
```

---

That being said, the way I usually go about dealing with [correlated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) passed to functions is with some  judicious [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), as you found yourself doing inside your original `handleSubmit()` implementation.  If you prefer the convenience of having a non-rest-parameter function signature, you could just use `toBool(value as any as TTrueOrFlase)` and move on.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAKjBOBXCB5eAxAhgGwM7QF4oByYJCYqAHxIDMd9iAoAYwHsA7XYKYNgITZtsUIgApgtAFywEyNFjwQAlDIBGQ7BEwdRAPl61RBIqXLMmAektQA7tAAWmAG7RMUWhFseAlhGwAJrh20LY6PHxQYPBsLBC4uAB0UADKbAC2bvDQHIjpahDwuAA0ULgZWdAsDhAsANYaAB4AtNg+ddDOOMi4VjbATjz2UNnR8RAcQz4DUAAGcOQKDBCziUygkLDobPDpACKYwO5EAN5MUFAg8WgAcmwAij3APpwyC-IYy+ce2RC0O+lHvFnq8oLl8oUmABfJh9MqYTJQDogYKYYIwba7A5HUpqRA8dgcVzwHjvVCfJS8NhQdwaYRQHxcYDaAKlCCJADmyX+8BpUAAUikUDcoABBAAKAEl1uBoDAUog1Olppj0jA2KKwD5RFAzhcrrhbg8ni8OOpNNoON9aL8eYCTaDwQV4NDYdZeA4fMEvR7oLREBwWCDdANDnY2IhAlEYnEElBOH6Ab5-AEaTx3M9Mmt3cMnK4qVBCcSIjVZIsKfgC7TNB4dh6ff7A8G1oTuGVFcrgKr0H4o0QADwiiCNZkcIJIiAgNhGDEA7GYPRia29gI3BEQGQ3YrfLrYZBvBVKlUA9WanwAbRuAF0mMp9LqoJYAFRlCqFtgBRyFaBPmww2EbNAorYNg4qYPACLBKcUCXgyujItOWxzocmBXjIl6lLOWIoZeV5XlAULnghM6qvON7uoBYogWBEHpFBMEAEQGkaQLcKaDGYXI5KKPg+E0OeDE2hAfwAqxwYcWCeTOjerY8E4Y5aIenY6mIiRqUSMjAaB4GQXeBAGHqDJGGIRLngADPhJhEEx1zwHcYnsXehkXLgHbHrsPYpiZzjmVepR8IIwjeeeACMV7KMoADc3xQlA-iVs57ZHl2AKeYEwUWaUplhVFMWukw8kBIpbnAGIxDMXZxrAqaxClMQ9BKMQd7umwdSYCABU6EVEBKdMZUVfZDocLVJC2JwQw7HUTWPjYhQxC6hXFclZVCSJuwOZwI0AMxRTN8ZtR1i09SVYgALKHA4iQQWOGRiHe-ZQGZiQAKxQAA-CQA1VWxm1QDI9W2qJQ0jSFu3unNOxMEAA)

Comment: wow, thanks for the great answer with links for more reading. By the looks of it, you've been trying to push for a fix in TS for things like this. Unfortunate the best answer for now seems to be to just cast as I've been doing..